# While installing through pods, its not installing and getting error "[!] No podspec found for `googleapis` in `

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-speech-api

I am doing Objective-C for iOS application and I want to install google cloud speech api, as per docs,

Google docs given example in following link, I followed for streaming

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C

I am trying to installing pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
but, its getting following error

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for googleapis from .
[!] No podspec found for googleapis in .
```

and my pod file is

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'appName' do
      # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
       # use_frameworks!

      # Pods for AppSpeak
       pod 'MBProgressHUD'
       pod 'Fabric'
       pod 'Crashlytics'
       pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
       end
```

**And my pod file version is cocoapods-1.2.1**

Can anyone help to fix this?

Comment: try with `:path =>` to `:git =>`

Comment: check your pod is outdated or else

Comment: tried, but no result, same error happening.

Comment: whats your pod verson

Comment: the verson is `CocoaPods 1.1.0` or else

Comment: cocoapods-1.2.1

Comment: " 'googleapis', :path => '.'" That doesn't make sense. You meant https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAPISwiftClient ? Or https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods where there is no "googleapis" listed? or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Streaming ?

Comment: try with `gem install cocoapods --pre`

Comment: try with `pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 1.0'`